# How to remove the Scrolling and fit to the Responsive screen?

Tags: html, iframe

```
  .iframe-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%; /* 16:9*/
  position: relative;
}

.iframe-container iframe {
   border: 0;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;

  <div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://ytj861vz7v7n6opm7n9xwq-on.drv.tw/HTML%20Coding/jotform.html" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" loading="lazy" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I also tried this in CSS:

overflow: hidden;
this not working

this is not Responsive also
Is there a way I can remove the scrollbar while still being able to scroll the whole page?

With just CSS or HTML, please.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `overflow: hidden` to the `body` tag in the CSS? Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bradberkobien/80d94png/3/